# A very strange problem related to Flash and Java

Tags: java, flash

I have created one simple program for showing webcam of the user. It works absolutely fine when i am running without integrating it in my java web application. But as soon as i copy paste the same files in Netbeans 6.8 and try to run it. My swf file is visible but the buttons in it are totally unclickable. I get the message of allow or deny showing webcam but the buttons are not clickable. It makes my application totally useless. I thought it's a minor issue but now it's getting on my nerves. I am trying it since 3 hours but didn't find any solution. I don't think anybody faced this issue till now that's why can't seem to find any thread in any forum on it in google.

I am using Netbeans 6.8, Ubuntu, Glassfish V3 and JSF.

Thanks in advance :).

**UPDATE:- It works fine on Windows XP. Then what can be the problem with Ubuntu? Any kind of permission rights that i need to give?**

**2nd UPDATE:- I think this is bug with Flash. I found that this code doesn't work :-**

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
                            codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0"
                            id="VideoConferenceAdmin" align="middle">
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                        <param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
                        <param NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="rootIp=localhost&amp;userName=admin&amp;roomName=test" />
                        <param name="movie" value="Conference/VideoConference.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <embed src="Conference/VideoConference.swf" wmode="window" FlashVars="rootIp=localhost&amp;userName=test&amp;roomName=test"
                               quality="high"  width="600" height="500"
                               name="VideoConference" align="middle"
                               allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false"
                               type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                               pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
                    </object>
```

And this one works :-

```
  <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
                            codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0"
                            id="VideoConferenceAdmin" align="middle">
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                        <param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
                        <param NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="rootIp=localhost&amp;userName=admin&amp;roomName=test" />
                        <param name="movie" value="Conference/VideoConference.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <embed src="Conference/VideoConference.swf" wmode="window" FlashVars="rootIp=localhost&amp;userName=test&amp;roomName=test"
                               quality="high"  
                               name="VideoConference" align="middle"
                               allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false"
                               type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                               pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
                    </object>
```

As you can see, just by removing the height and width attribute the panels of Flash settings work fine. I know you will find me funny but i am not. You can check out on your own if you don't trust me.

Now, my question would be, can anybody tell me how do i set height and width of swf? I want it to be 600px width and 500px height. Even the style attribute doesn't work. Can i set height and width from within Flash? because without explicitly setting height and width, it looks very small. I think this should be very easy for all now. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width and height attributes on both the object and embed tags. Check out this [page in the knowledgebase](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_Required_attributes).

Having said that, I would strongly recommend to use [swfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed the player.  This should help you to get rid of your problems and provides a more readable code.